# Cannot squash merge in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop, git-squash

When trying to squash merge 3 commits in GitHub Desktop, I was warned with the following error message:

> Unable to squash. Squashing replays all commits up to the last one required for the squash. A merge commit cannot exist among those commits.

As far as I can tell, I am not trying to squash a merge commit, so I'm not sure what the issue is here. I haven't been able to find other folks encountering the same problem. What am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to squash the two highlighted commits into the one commit above them ("Improved Redeem Display"):

[image: Squash merge attempt]

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a rebase from the default repo branch to my branch and then the squash operation was permitted. If you are using merge instead of rebase, you can try updating from your default branch.